# Ways to generalize C++ code with different similar types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

Currently I have the following code:

```
static void markPoolsFree(const TNetgroupPools &group_info, TObjectID netiface) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i<group_info.public_pools.length();i ++ ) {
        SDK::revokeIPPoolFromNetworkInterface(group_info.public_pools[i],netiface);
    }

    for (size_t i =0 ; i<group_info.private_pool.length(); i++) {
        SDK::revokeIPPoolFromNetworkInterface(group_info.private_pool[i].pool_id,
                                              netiface);
    }
}
```

which has basically the same logic, but differents in types `group_info.public_pools[i]` and `group_info.private_pool[i]`, that's why in second loop we have to add `.pool_id` member call. These types are different and don't have any relationships.

I want to rewrite this code to make it more general, for example something like this (sketch):

```
// template function
template <typename Container, typename PredArgs>
static void revokeIPPool(const Container &pool, TObjectID netiface,
                         bool (*pred)(PredArgs pool_id, PredArgs netiface_id))
{
     for (size_t i = 0; i < pool.length(); ++i) {
         if (pred(pool[i], netiface)) {
             SDK::revokeIPPoolFromNetworkInterface(pool[i], netiface);
         }

     }
}

// calling code
static void markPoolsFree(const TNetgroupPools &group_info, TObjectID netiface) {
    revokeIPPool(group_info.public_pools, netiface, SDK::isPredicateTrue);
    revokeIPPool(group_info.private_pool, netiface, SDK::isPredicateTrue);
}
```

But the problem is in different types for `public_pools` and `private_pool`.

**Question:**
Could you give all ways how is possible to generalize this code with examples? I need C++03 code, but C++11/C++14 is acceptable.

**My thoughts:**

1. Instead of `SDK::revokeIPPoolFromNetworkInterface` make `wrapperIPPool` with overloads for both types and call `SDK::revokeIPPoolFromNetworkInterface` internally.
2. Overload `revokeIPPool` for both types (but it's code duplication, no improvement against original code)
3. Partial function template specialization for `revokeIPPool` (is this possible?)
4. Full function template specialization for `revokeIPPool`
5. Wrap function `revokeIPPool` in class and make partial class template specialization.

**Questions:**

1. Wich of my thoughts are correct?
2. What's about advantages and shortcomings?
3. Which is more idiomatic for C++03 or C++11?
4. Is there other solutions?

Comment: The `.pool_id` of the private pool is the same type as the `public_pool`.  Overload a function that on public pools, returns the input, and on private pools, returns `.pool_id`.  That can get you half way.

Answer (score 3):

In C++03 I'd use template specialization on a traits class. (The main reason for going through a traits class, rather than using direct function specialisation, or overload is that you can perform partial template specialisation for classes, but not functions - and while its not needed here, it may be something that is useful later )

```
static void markPoolsFree(const TNetgroupPools &group_info, TObjectID netiface) {
    markPoolsFreeImpl(group_info.public_pools, netiface);
    markPoolsFreeImpl(group_info.private_pools, netiface);
}

template<typename T>
static void markPoolsFreeImpl(POOLS pools, TObjectID netiface) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i<pools.length();i ++ ) {
       PoolId poolid = PoolListTrait<POOLS>::get(pools,i);
       SDK::revokeIPPoolFromNetworkInterface(poolid,netiface);
    }
}

template<typename T> class PoolListTrait {};

template<> class PoolListTrait<PublicPoolList> {
  static PoolId get(PublicPoolList pools, int i) { return pools[i]; }
}

template<> class PoolListTrait<PrivatePoolList> {
  static PoolId get(PrivatePoolList pools, int i) { return pools[i].pool_id; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Dunno if generic lambdas (C++14) are an acceptable solution for you:

```
auto revoke_pool = [](auto &pool, TObjectID netiface, auto extract_item)
{
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < pool.length(); ++i)
        SDK::revokeIPPoolFromNetworkInterface(extract_item(pool, i), netiface);
};
```

Then you only hace to define a lambda to access the pool item.

```
revoke_pool(group_info.public_pools, netiface, [](auto &pool, std::size_t idx) { return pool[idx]; });
revoke_pool(group_info.private_pool, netiface, [](auto &pool, std::size_t idx) { return pool[idx].pool_id; });
```

Answer (score 2):

As we go from C++03 to C++11 to C++14, our solution gets shorter both in terms of being less total code and in terms of being able to be more localized - both clear wins. In C++14 we can do it in just one 10-line function, whereas in C++03 we needed 4 functions. Here's how I would do it in each of the three feature sets:

---

C++03: **Functors**! Basically how you were expected to use every standard algorithm back in the day (or free functions).

```
template <typename POOL, typename EXTRACTOR>
static void markPoolsFreeImpl(const POOL &pool, TObjectID netiface, 
    EXTRACTOR ex)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < pool.length(); ++i) {
        SDK::removeIPPoolFromNetworkInterface(ex(pool[i]), netiface);
    }
}


static void markPoolsFree(const TNetgroupPools &group_info, TObjectID netiface) {
    markPoolsFreeImpl(group_info.public_pools,
                  netiface,
                  PublicExtractor());

    markPoolsFreeImpl(group_info.private_pools,
                  netiface,
                  PrivateExtractor());
}

// fill in T, U, V as appropriate here, I dunno what they are
struct PublicExtractor {
    T operator()(const U& item) const { return item; }
};

struct PrivateExtractor {
    T operator()(const V& item) const { return item.pool_id; }
};
```

This could also look like:

```
T PublicExtractor(const U& item) { return item; }
```

And just pass it in without the extra `()`s. If we accidentally provide `markPoolsFreeImpl` an `EXTRACTOR` with the wrong `operator()`, it just won't compile pointing to the line where it's called. This isn't great, but it's about as good as we can do.

---

C++11: **Lambdas**! The `markPoolsFreeImpl` function can look the same, it's just that instead of defining our functors wherever, we can definte them inline:

```
static void markPoolsFree(const TNetgroupPools &group_info, TObjectID netiface) {
    markPoolsFreeImpl(group_info.public_pools,
                  netiface,
                  [](const U& item) { return item; });

    markPoolsFreeImpl(group_info.private_pools,
                  netiface,
                  [](const V& item) { return item.pool_id; });
}
```

Furthermore, we can make our error messages clearer in case we pass the wrong kind of extractor function (again, fill in `T` as appropriate):

```
template <typename POOL, typename EXTRACTOR>
static void markPoolsFreeImpl(const POOL &pool, TObjectID netiface, 
    EXTRACTOR ex)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, decltype(ex(pool[0]))>::value, 
                  "invalid EXTRACTOR: must return a T");

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < pool.length(); ++i) {
        SDK::removeIPPoolFromNetworkInterface(ex(pool[i]), netiface);
    }
}
```

---

C++14: **Simpler Lambdas**! We don't even have to identify the `U` and `V`:

```
static void markPoolsFree(const TNetgroupPools &group_info, TObjectID netiface) {
    markPoolsFreeImpl(group_info.public_pools,
                  netiface,
                  [](const auto& item) { return item; });

    markPoolsFreeImpl(group_info.private_pools,
                  netiface,
                  [](const auto& item) { return item.pool_id; });
}
```

And can even turn `markPoolsFreeImpl` into a local lambda:

```
static void markPoolsFree(const TNetgroupPools &group_info, TObjectID netiface) {
    // netiface is captured
    auto impl = [&](const auto& pool, auto ex) {
        static_assert(std::is_same<T, decltype(ex(pool[0]))>::value, "");

        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < pool.length(); ++i) {
            SDK::removeIPPoolFromNetworkInterface(ex(pool[i]), netiface);
        }
    });

    impl(group_info.public_pools, [](const auto& item) { return item; });
    impl(group_info.private_pools, [](const auto& item) { return item.pool_id; });
}
```